# Waiting on compilation to finish

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am using compile to pull new files from source tree using mercurial "hg pull".
I am performing a save of all buffers before the pull and would like to "refresh all opened buffers" after the compilation "pulling" finishes.
I tried experimenting with compilation-finish-functions but found out that the functions added to the list will be executed after "every" compilation. Since I use compile to search IDs "gid" I don't want to refresh opened files on every search.
How can I wait on compilation to finish before refreshing opened files "only" while inside a command and not on every compile outside of the command.
Here is the code:

```
; From http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompileCommand
(defun compile-pkg (&optional command startdir)
  "Compile a package, moving up to the parent directory
  containing configure.ac, if it exists. Start in startdir if defined,
  else start in the current directory."
  (interactive)
  (let ((dirname) (dir-buffer nil))
    (setq startdir (expand-file-name (if startdir startdir ".")))
    (setq command  (if command command compile-command))
    (setq dirname (upward-find-file "Makefile" startdir))
;    (setq dirname (if dirname dirname (upward-find-file "Makefile" startdir)))
;    (setq dirname (if dirname dirname (expand-file-name ".")))
    ; We've now worked out where to start. Now we need to worry about
    ; calling compile in the right directory
    (save-excursion
      (setq dir-buffer (find-file-noselect dirname))
      (set-buffer dir-buffer)
      (compile command)
      (kill-buffer dir-buffer)
      )))

(defun upward-find-file (filename &optional startdir)
  "Move up directories until we find a certain filename. If we
  manage to find it, return the containing directory. Else if we
  get to the toplevel directory and still can't find it, return
  nil. Start at startdir or . if startdir not given"
  (let ((dirname (expand-file-name
                  (if startdir startdir ".")))
        (found nil) ; found is set as a flag to leave loop if we find it
        (top nil))  ; top is set when we get
                    ; to / so that we only check it once
    ; While we've neither been at the top last time nor have we found
    ; the file.
    (while (not (or found top))
      ; If we're at / set top flag.
      (if (string= (expand-file-name dirname) "/")
          (setq top t))
      ; Check for the file
      (if (file-exists-p (expand-file-name filename dirname))
          (setq found t)
        ; If not, move up a directory
        (setq dirname (expand-file-name ".." dirname))))
    ; return statement
    (if found (concat dirname "/") nil)))

(defun compile-hgpull ()
  (interactive)
  (save-all-buffers)
  (compile-pkg "hg pull -u")
; if (compile finished) -> (revert-all-buffers)
  )

(global-set-key [f1]    'compile-hgpull)
```

Answer (score 2):

compile is async.  So, you have two choices.

One, don't use compile.  Instead use one of the other ways to invoke a shell command, like shell-command or start-process or call-process.  I think this is probably preferred; I don't see why you'd need to use compile here.

Two, set compilation-finish-function.

Comment: Thanks Tom.
I would like to see the results of the compilation on the compilations window.
Could you elaborate more on how to use set compilation-finish-function?

Comment: Make an attempt, then ask a new question about any problems you encounter. Also perhaps you should accept Tom's answer.

Comment: compilation-finish-function has been deprecated since Emacs 22. The documentation recommends instead adding to the compilation-finish-functions hook. @andy256: why are you recommending the asker accept an answer he's not yet sure actually solves the problem?

Comment: Andy, I already tried using shell-command even before asking the question here. And as I stated I want the compilation window for many different reasons. I am planning on using this method to perform other shell commands like making/pushing/pulling...etc
Aaron, I already did research on this function you are referring to but found that you  can ad'hook other functions to it "outside" of the function I am binding to F1. Since I am using compilation for "gid" as well I don;t want refreshing opened files to happen on each compilation but only when pressing F1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a shell-command synchronously, and then see its output, it might be easier to use `shell-command-to-string` than `compile`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, as I explained above, I want the compilation window because it shows more information. I just need a way to findout when the compilation finishes "inside" my function. I don't want a function to be executed "everytime" a compilation finishes related to me function or not.