# Passing a command as argument to a function in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am a novice in elisp. So excuse my novice question.
I am trying to pass a "command" to the function compile-pkg, but I keep getting wrong argument in emacs for the function compile-make().

```
(defun compile-pkg (&optional command startdir)
  "Compile a package, moving up to the parent directory
  containing configure.ac, if it exists. Start in startdir if defined,
  else start in the current directory."
  (interactive)

  (let ((dirname)
    (dir-buffer nil))
    (setq startdir (expand-file-name (if startdir startdir ".")))
    (setq command  (if command command compile-command))

    (setq dirname (upward-find-file "Makefile" startdir))
    (setq dirname (if dirname dirname (expand-file-name ".")))
    ; We've now worked out where to start. Now we need to worry about
    ; calling compile in the right directory
    (save-excursion
      (setq dir-buffer (find-file-noselect dirname))
      (set-buffer dir-buffer)
      (compile command)
      (kill-buffer dir-buffer))))

(defun upward-find-file (filename &optional startdir)
  "Move up directories until we find a certain filename. If we
  manage to find it, return the containing directory. Else if we
  get to the toplevel directory and still can't find it, return
  nil. Start at startdir or . if startdir not given"

  (let ((dirname (expand-file-name
          (if startdir startdir ".")))
    (found nil) ; found is set as a flag to leave loop if we find it
    (top nil))  ; top is set when we get
            ; to / so that we only check it once

    ; While we've neither been at the top last time nor have we found
    ; the file.
    (while (not (or found top))
      ; If we're at / set top flag.
      (if (string= (expand-file-name dirname) "/")
      (setq top t))

      ; Check for the file
      (if (file-exists-p (expand-file-name filename dirname))
      (setq found t)
    ; If not, move up a directory
    (setq dirname (expand-file-name ".." dirname))))
    ; return statement
    (if found (concat dirname "/") nil)))

(defun compile-make ()
  (compile-pkg "make"))

(global-set-key [f1] 'compile-make)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing that is wrong is that you need `compile-make` to be a command, which you can do with the simple change:

```
(defun compile-make ()
  (interactive)
  (compile-pkg "make"))
```

Take a look at the Emacs lisp tutorial, specifically the section on [Making a Function Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Interactive.html#Interactive) to understand why `interactive` was necessary.

*Note:* It's generally helpful if you cut/paste the exact error message you were seeing.  I imagine it was:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, compile-make
```

Comment: That was the message that I saw.correct.
I fixed the error by doing this:
(setq makestring "make")
(defun compile-make ()
  "Like 'compile', but uses compile-pkg"
  (interactive)
  (save-all-buffers)
  (compile-pkg makestring))
But not sure why I needed to use setq and not pass the argument directly.

Comment: @Ammari the fix is the `(interactive)` - take it out and you'll see that you get the error again.

Comment: On a different note, if I am trying to refresh all opened files "reread them from disk", how would I wait on the compilation to finish first before doing (revert-all-buffers)?

Comment: That's probably best addressed via a new question - so that others can find it and make use of it.

Comment: Done.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241100/waiting-on-compilation-to-finish/

Please advice if you have any pointers.